# Encrypting value of a src in html/js

Tags: javascript, html, security, encryption

Just need help with some basic encryption.

```html
<script src='https://itzplayz0001.github.io/Portfolio'>
```

This here is my html script tag linking my js file to an external js file, now I want to encrypt the value of the src how would I do that? any ideas? Any answer will be appreciated :)

I thought I would use *obfuscator.io*, I did that but got something that doesn't help

**Output from obfuscator.io**

```js
var _0x49fd=['https://itzplayz0001.github.io/Portfolio'];(function(_0x153e5f,_0x49fd5d){var _0x20eae4=function(_0x5348b3){while(--_0x5348b3){_0x153e5f['push'](_0x153e5f['shift']());}};_0x20eae4(++_0x49fd5d);}(_0x49fd,0x1f3));var _0x20ea=function(_0x153e5f,_0x49fd5d){_0x153e5f=_0x153e5f-0x0;var _0x20eae4=_0x49fd[_0x153e5f];return _0x20eae4;};var _0x140a62=_0x20ea;src=_0x140a62('0x0');
```

As you guys can see everything except the link was encrypted :/

Thanks for reading <3

Comment: Nothing was encrypted. Obfuscation is not encryption.

Comment: obfuscator.io also providing more option to obfuscate the code without explicitly show your content. Go ahead and try it

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way by using btoa / atob (base64 encoding):

```
const scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.setAttribute('src', window.atob('aHR0cHM6Ly9pdHpwbGF5ejAwMDEuZ2l0aHViLmlvL1BvcnRmb2xpbw=='));
document.head.appendChild(scr)
```

To get that encoded string:

```
const encodedSrc = window.btoa('https://itzplayz0001.github.io/Portfolio')
console.log(encodedSrc)
```

If you need more advanced (real) encryption take a look at : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt